# Insertar campos dinamicos

Tags: php, array, bucle-for

estoy intentando insertar unos input tanto fijos como unos dinamicos...
Es un formulario donde dos compos son dinamicos y el resto no se deben repetir...

al solicitar la insercción o solo me agrega el último elemento o bien me inserta todo las veces que dura el búcle

Este es mi código

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($quantity) ; $i++) { 

$invoice = array(
"type"         => $tipo_comprobante,
"customer"     => $id_cliente,
"items"        => array(
array(
  "quantity" => $quantity[$i],
  "product"  => $id_producto[$i]
 )
 ),
"payment_form" => $forma_pago,
"folio_number" => $folio_number,
"series"       => "F"
);

}
$facturapi->Invoices->create( $invoice );

?>
```

Está parte es la que debe ser dinamica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servira dividiendo y al finalizar concatenando?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a algo así:

```php
$invoice = array(
    "type"         => $tipo_comprobante,
    "customer"     => $id_cliente,
    "payment_form" => $forma_pago,
    "folio_number" => $folio_number,
    "series"       => "F"
);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($quantity) ; $i++) { 
    if (isset( $invoice['items'] )) {
        $invoice['items'][] = [
            "quantity" => $quantity[$i],
            "product"  => $id_producto[$i]
        ];
    } else {
        $invoice['items'] = [[
            "quantity" => $quantity[$i],
            "product"  => $id_producto[$i]
        ]];
    }
}

$facturapi->Invoices->create( $invoice );
```

donde lo que hacemos primero es definir los campos invariables de la factura, y después recorrer las cantidades y agregarlas a la variable $invoice comprobando primero si existen elementos previamente o si es la primera vez que se agregan.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono

Comment: es posible me ayudes con otra consulta similar...