# Hacer un While dentro de un Array

Tags: php

Estoy intentado enviar datos a una API mediante un array, sin embargo algunos de los campos tienen que ser dinámicos y necesito insertar un WHILE para enviar de uno a más registros...

Este es mi código

```
require("conexion_factura2.php");

    $invoice = [
      "type"         => "P",
      "customer"     => "6238e49600690b002d5f6cde",
      "folio_number" => "1000",
      "use" => "CP01",
      "complements"=>[[
      "type" => "pago",
      "data"=>[
            [
              "payment_form" => "99", 
              "date" => "2022-07-27",
              "related_documents"=>[
                [
                  "uuid" => "77137f7f-21df-47d2-aa05-167853b843c9",
                  "amount" => "189",
                  "taxes" => [],
                  "installment" => "1",
                  "last_balance" => "189",
                  "folio_number" => "1002"
                ]      
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ];

    $facturapi->Invoices->create( $invoice );
```

Así tal cual está sí funciona...

Esta es la parte que necesito que sea mediante un WHILE

```
    [
    "uuid" => "77137f7f-21df-47d2-aa05-167853b843c9",
    "amount" => "189",
    "taxes" => [],
    "installment" => "1",
    "last_balance" => "189",
    "folio_number" => "1002"
    ]
```

Comment: ¿Nos muestras los métodos `Invoices()` y `create()`?

Comment: La variable `$invoice` solo contendrá la información para crear una peticion o contendrá varios para enviar?

Comment: Solo una petición...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta pregunta es muy similar a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/545592/263200).

Prueba con esto:

```
require("conexion_factura2.php");

$invoice = [
    "type"         => "P",
    "customer"     => "6238e49600690b002d5f6cde",
    "folio_number" => "1000",
    "use" => "CP01",
    "complements"=>[
        [
            "type" => "pago",
            "data"=>[
                [
                    "payment_form" => "99", 
                    "date" => "2022-07-27",
                    "related_documents"=> []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

while (expr) {
    $invoice['complements'][0]['data'][0]['related_documents'][] = [
                  "uuid" => "77137f7f-21df-47d2-aa05-167853b843c9",
                  "amount" => "189",
                  "taxes" => [],
                  "installment" => "1",
                  "last_balance" => "189",
                  "folio_number" => "1002"
    ];
}

$facturapi->Invoices->create( $invoice );
```

donde **(expr)** es lo que tengas previsto para el while.  Dado que tu pregunta carece de más datos esto es lo único que puedo responder, y espero que te ayude a comprender cómo hacerlo en tu caso real.

Doy por sentado algunas cosas en esta respuesta, que son:

1. **complements** solo va a contener un array dentro de otro array, de ahí que haya usado el `[0]` para apuntar a el único array que espero encontrar.
2. Lo mismo para **data**

Comment: Muchas gracias!